# How do I change local notification data on trigger in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to change the data in my local notification using the on.("trigger") method. However, it keeps showing the same notification again and again with the same data. This way I know the notificaiton is working but it's not changing data on the trigger.

```
Ionic Framework: 3.1.1

Node: 6.10.0

OS: Windows 7

Ionic CLI: 3.0.0

Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
```

I'm using the following code for the trigger:

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {

    // Get the JSON data from our itemApi
    this.itemApi.getItems().then(data => {

        this.items = data;

        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length)

        // Select the random object an pass it to the oneItem object
        this.oneItem = this.items[randomNumber];

    });

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ---- Function for changing data on trigger
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a callback function on the schedule trigger - populates the notification with new data
    this.localNotifications.on("trigger", function() {

            // Get the JSON data from our itemApi
            this.itemApi.getItems().then(data => {

                this.items = data;

                let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length)

                // Select the random object an pass it to the oneItem object
                this.oneItem = this.items[randomNumber];

                // The notification
                let notification = {
                    id:1,
                    title: this.oneItem.word,
                    text: this.oneItem.description,
                    every: "minute"
                };

                this.notifications.push(notification);

                this.notifications.update(this.notifications);

            });
    });
}
```

Do you know why it's not working?

Comment: did you checked in console is `trigger` event triggered?

Comment: I can't fire notifications in the browser, only while emulating a device.. How can I check whether the event is triggered?